# CSS transparent triangle over background with half-transparent borders

Tags: html, css, background

[image]

I wonder if it's possible to achieve that with CSS?

My problem is those overlapping "borders" - I could move them with translate so they won't overlap, but then I'd need to adjust the angle degrees to have correct vertex of an angle.

Are there any better solutions to do that?

```css
.container {
  background: url("https://images.pexels.com/photos/310452/pexels-photo-310452.jpeg?cs=srgb&dl=pexels-dom-j-310452.jpg&fm=jpg");
  height: 300px;
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
}

.left {
  width: 40%;
  height: 100%;
  background: white;
}

.right {
  width: 60%;
  height: 100%;
  background: transparent;
}

.right:before,
.right:after {
  content: '';
  width: 11%;
  height: 100%;
  background: white;
  /* background-clip:padding-box; */
  position: absolute;
  left: 40%;
}

.right:before {
  top: 0;
  transform: rotate(30deg) translate(-80%, -30%);
  /* border-right: 30px solid rgba(0, 0, 136 ,0.5); */
  box-shadow: 30px 0 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 136, 0.5);
}

.right:after {
  bottom: 0;
  transform: rotate(-30deg) translate(-80%, 40%);
  /* border-right: 30px solid rgba(0, 0, 136 ,0.5); */
  box-shadow: 30px 0 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 136, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="right"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: @XBuilder egyptian gods... dumb me. Thank you! Please add it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an idea using gradients and masks. You will need two kind of gradient and both should be similar within the mask and background properties

```css
.container {
  background: 
    linear-gradient(120deg, transparent 40%,rgba(0, 0, 136, 0.5) 40.5% 45%, transparent 45.5%) top   /100% 50% no-repeat,
    linear-gradient(60deg,  transparent 40%,rgba(0, 0, 136, 0.5) 40.5% 45%, transparent 45.5%) bottom/100% 50% no-repeat,
    url("https://images.pexels.com/photos/310452/pexels-photo-310452.jpeg?cs=srgb&dl=pexels-dom-j-310452.jpg&fm=jpg");
  -webkit-mask:
    linear-gradient(120deg, transparent 40%,#fff 40.5%) top   /100% 50% no-repeat,
    linear-gradient(60deg,  transparent 40%,#fff 40.5%) bottom/100% 50% no-repeat;
  height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container"></div>
```

Another version with different values

```css
.container {
  background: 
    linear-gradient(131deg, transparent 40%,rgba(0, 0, 136, 0.5) 40.1% calc(40% + 18px), transparent calc(40.1% + 18px)) top   /100% 40% no-repeat,
    linear-gradient(60deg,  transparent 40%,rgba(0, 0, 136, 0.5) 40.1% calc(40% + 20px), transparent calc(40.1% + 20px)) bottom/100% 60% no-repeat,
    url("https://images.pexels.com/photos/310452/pexels-photo-310452.jpeg?cs=srgb&dl=pexels-dom-j-310452.jpg&fm=jpg");
  -webkit-mask:
    linear-gradient(131deg, transparent 40%,#fff 40.1%) top   /100% 40% no-repeat,
    linear-gradient(60deg,  transparent 40%,#fff 40.1%) bottom/100% 60% no-repeat;
  height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container"></div>
```

Simply adjust both gradients like you want to get the final shape